# how validate a text box when i select some values in other column

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How to validate a text box which depends on other column? Which is like when O select particular values.based on selected value the validation is reference number must be required. I need validation in view file only.

The exact validation is in below code there is buyer col and `external_ref_number` cols. So when I select particular value in buyer `the external_ref_number` is must be required.please help me to solve this

```
<div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('user')) has-error @endif">

    {{ Form::label('user', 'Buyer *', array('class'=> 'col-lg-2 control-label')) }}

    <div class="col-lg-4">

        {{ Form::text('user', Input::old('user'), array('class'=> 'form-control', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'readonly' => 'readonly')) }}    
        {{ $errors->first('user', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') }}

        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="pull-left"><button id="selectUserBtn" class="btn btn-primary selectUserBtn" href="/transaction/ajaxcustomer"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Select Buyer</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group required {{ $errors->first('external_ref_number', 'has-error') }}">

    {{ Form::label('external_ref_number', 'External reference number ', array('class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label')) }}

    <div class="col-lg-4">

        {{ Form::text('external_ref_number', $orderMappedInfo['external_ref_number'], ['placeholder' => 'External reference number', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}

        {{ $errors->first('external_ref_number', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') }}

    </div>
</div>
```

There is buyer col and `external_ref_number` cols. So when I select particular value in buyer the `external_ref_number` is must be required. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Seems like client side work,Try using jquery validation

Comment: @ViperTecPro server-side validation must also be employed _as well_ though, because JS checks are easy to bypass with a minimal amount of knowledge. JS validation is nice for user experience but provides no actual protection to the application or data.

Comment: Yes of course  Server-side validation is required but with the help of js or ajax, you can make it more intractable.Without server-side validation no application is safe.

Comment: yes i server side validation is required .but my requirement is .when i select perticular buyer name .the external reference number is show otherwise hide or enable or disable

Answer (score 0):

you can use required_with or required_if for more details visit
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-if